# Setting up a test in rspec with multiple "it" blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, bdd

Say I have an instance method that does many different things that I need to test, something like `store#process_order`. I'd like to test that it sends an email to the customer, adds an entry in the orders table, charges a credit card, etc. What's the best way to set this up in rspec? Currently, I'm using rspec and factory girl I do something like this:

```
describe Store do
  describe "#process_order" do
    before do
      @store = Factory(:store)
      @order = Factory(:order)
      # call the process method
      @store.process_order(@order)
    end

    it 'sends customer an email' do
      ...
    end
    it 'inserts order to db' do
      ...
    end
    it 'charges credit card' do
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

But it feels really tedious. Is this really the right way to write a spec for a method that I need to make sure does several different things?

Note: I'm not interested in answers about whether or not this is good design. It's just an example I made up to help w/ my question - how to write these types of specs.

Comment: If it does several different things, you should have several different tests, which you do. DRY is not a rule!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are doing is fine and I think it's the way rspec is intended to be used.  Every statement (specification) about your app gets its own block.

You might consider using `before (:all) do` so that the order only has to get processed once but this can introduce dependencies on the order the specs are run.

You could combine all the code inside `describe "#process_order"` into one big `it` block if you wanted to, but then it would be less readable and rspec would give you less useful error messages when a spec fails.  Go head and add `raise` to one of your tests and see what a nice error message you can get from rspec if you do it the way you are currently doing it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good method because you can identify which element is broken if something breaks in the future.  I am all for testing things individually.  I tend not to check things get inserted into the database as you are then rails functionality.  I simply check the validity of the object instead.

This is the method that is used in the RSpec book too.  I would certainly recommend reading it if you are unsure about anything related to RSpec.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test the entire process then we're talking about an integration test, not a unit test. If you want to test #process_order *method* which does several things, then I'd expect those things mean calling other methods. So, I would add #should_receive expectations and make sure that all paths are covered. Then I would spec all those methods separately so I have a nice unit spec suite for everything. In the end I would definitely write an integration/acceptance spec which checks if all those pieces are working together.

Also, I would use #let to setup test objects which removes dependencies between spec examples (it blocks). Otherwise a failure of one of the examples may cause a failure in other example giving you an incorrect feedback.